# command line flag to disable ssl certification validation in java

Tags: java

I am working on a Spring Boot application which calls a [SVIX](https://docs.svix.com/) webhook .

```java
Svix svix = new Svix("TOKEN");
        try {
            svix.getMessage().create("APP_ID",
                    new MessageIn()
                            .eventType(rd.getEventType())
                            .payload(ow.writeValueAsString(payload)));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting the following error on running it

```bash
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am working on a corporate network and I think it is causing a certificate issue. ( I had same issue in postman and clicking `Disable SSL Verification` had solved it .)

I am looking for a command line flag to disable the ssl verification. So far I've tried

- `-Djdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification=true`
- `-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true`
- `-Dtrust_all_cert=true`
- `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false`

but nothing works

I am using Spring Boot version 3 and Java Version 17.

I understand disabling ssl verification is not a good solution . But I want it for development

Comment: "I understand disabling ssl verification is not a good solution . But I want it for development" Even for development it is still not a good idea at all because it will just encroach sloppy programming into everything and it will leak in production.

Comment: SUGGESTION: review this link: https://www.javacodemonk.com/disable-ssl-validation-in-spring-resttemplate-e2c53583.   Please post back what you've tried, and whether or not it worked.

Comment: @paulsm4 I am not using rest template to make the api call . I am using SVIX's sdk. I don't know what it uses underneath.

Comment: "I am looking for a command line flag to disable the ssl verification": you won't find one, and there will never be one. Sun/Oracle would have to be mad to introduce a security breach like this into Java. And you don't "need it for development". You need to *solve* the problem, not just ignore it.

Comment: @user207421 I am on a corporate network which puts its certificate in the certificate chain. The certificate changes dynamically and adding to trusted certs won't work . How do I _solve_ the problem ?

Comment: @user207421  why Sun/Oracle is mad to keep a flag like [ `-Dtrust_all_cert=true`  ](https://docs.oracle.com/communications/E76289_01/doc.1001/e76292/sg_imp_security.htm#IMSSG166)

Comment: @Sushant I agree. They are mad. But that's only for IMS, not the whole of Java.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an incomplete certificate store installed. Have you tried updating ca-certificates?

E.g. on Debian (in Docker):

```
RUN apt-get update ;\
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
      curl \
      ca-certificates=20210119; \
    update-ca-certificates; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```